# How do I get in VSCode (Ruby) GIT changes visible on the left margin?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Before, in VSCode, when code was changed removed compared to the GIT repository, a red line was shown in the left margin, and green lines for added code (see the picture with the red circle below)

[image]

I copied the above screenshot from my colleague, but he doesn't know how to fix this issue on my system.

I installed GitLens, but it seems not to make any difference, neither as any settings (unless we missed one).

How can I get the green/red lines visible again?

Comment: `scm.diffDecorations` setting?

Comment: @matt I also would have expected this setting, but it doesn't show any diff.